# What is the difference between 'ng-click' and 'ng-mousedown' directives

Tags: angularjs, mouseevent, angularjs-ng-click

The line `<div ng-mousedown="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">Click me!</div>` means,'Executing an expression when a mouse click occurs.

similarly, the line `<button ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">Click me!</button>` means, 'Increase the count variable by one, each time the button is clicked'

> Now what confuses me, is when should i use ng-click and when should i use ng-mousedown?? I mean what exact difference is there between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When should I use them?

You decide, they give you the tools, you build the application with them.

`ng-mousedown` will trigger whenever any of your mouse buttons is clicked over the element (**it doesn't wait till you release the key**), this can be used to have custom functionality for in your application depending on your needs (like a menu or zoom effect etc.)

`ng-click` will trigger when the left mouse button is pressed and released on that element, or when the active element from the keyboard navigation is activated (using <kbd>**tab**</kbd> and `tabindex`)

Comment: Some people might use the mousedown to make the user feel the app is more responsive. But in most applications you should use the click event: it's what people are accustomed to and communicates your intent that you want to do something when the user clicks on an element. Mousedown becomes more useful when you want to do things like drag and drop...

Comment: Also, the edited comment about using keyboard navigation to click elements is a great reason to avoid using mousedown, b/c people using the keyboard won't be able to click things when using mousedown.

Comment: @SunilD. Yeah, but that's more of a UX issue, you should design the application in a way that feels intuitive to use. And you can use angular touch library for better control on touch events in mobile apps.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-mousedown` comes after `ng-click` 350ms.

Some time you should use `ng-mousedown`. e.g. if you click a button and remove it.

If you use `ng-click`, then the `ng-click` event will fall through to the element (which is not the parent element of the element) under the button.

If you don't want the event fall through to the element, you would better use `ng-mousedown`.

Answer (score 0):

With `ng-click`, if you click and hold down, your event will not fire until you let go of the mouse button.

With `ng-mousedown`, if you click and hold down, your event will have fired.  You do not have to let go of the mouse button.